# Writing: [\/] (\ or / regex) correctly?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches either `\` or `/`.

No matter in what order I write it:

```
[//\]
```

or

```
[/\\]
```

It is somehow escaping either my square bracket or my forward slash. What's the correct way of showing this particular case?

Comment: Now that I noticed, I meant to write `[\\/]` or `[/\\]` but I'm sure most people got it. I won't edit my answer since the answer below makes reference to my mistake and I don't want to confuse users. Hope this sorts out any doubt on my logic if anyone had it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are escaping the closing bracket in the second regex, and the first one won't even compile as a string. You want

```
"[/\\\\]"
```

Both of your regex in the question are correct *plain* regex. However, since the regex is specified inside a Java string literal, to specify a `\`, you need to escape it `\\`. Therefore, we end up with `"[/\\\\]"` or `"[\\\\/]"`.

In summary, to correctly specify `\` in the regex, we must escape it `\\`. And to correctly specify `\\` in Java string literal, we must add on another layer of escaping `\\\\`.

Comment: `a literal \ in a regular expression we must write \\\\.` No. ``\\`` is enough. The reason is that we need another layer of escaping with Java literal string.

Comment: I take my liberty to edit your answer. If you don't like it, feel free to roll back.